# Shortest root using machine learning/AI

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Assume that I have set of points scattered on the XY plane, and i have two points say start and end point any where in XY plane. I want to find the shortest path between start and end point without touching scattered points. The path has to maintain certain offset ( i.e assume path has some width ). 
How to approach this kind of problems in programming, Are there any algorithms in machine learning.

Comment: I... what are you planning on having the machine "learn"? There are plenty of shortest path algorithms that exist, ML isn't just a buzzword. Many people apply a modified Dijkstra's algorithm for ML purposes, but... very different core concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need a greedy algorithm for the shortest path?
Try Dijsktra's Algorithm.
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-6-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm/

The shortest solution for the lowest price.

Comment: Ancient algorithm that has withstood the test of time with only minimum modifications and optimizations. Definitely the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can also consider the A* algorithm.

This finds the same solution as Dijkstra's algorithm, but often at a lower computational cost (which might be important in your case, since after the space discretization you might end up with a large grid).

This is because A* uses a heuristic to bias the search, so that it looks into more promising directions first (*e.g.* moving towards the target is in principle a good idea, so this is attempted first).

You can see some visualizations of A* running [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19h1g22hby8) and (side by side with Dijkstra's algorithm - thanks @Thrawn for the link), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g024lzsknDo).

Comment: you can see a visualsation of both here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g024lzsknDo

A* is a very valid alternative.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a machine learning problem but an optimization problem.

> So you need a greedy algorithm for the shortest path

Indeed it could be solved this way but the challenge is to represent your grid as a graph... 
For example, decomposing the grid in a n x n matrix. In your shortest path algorithm, a node is an element of your matrix (so you exclude the elements of the matrice that contains the scattered points) and the weight of the arcs are the distance.

However n must be small since shortest path algotithms are np-hard problems...

Maybe other algorithms exist for this specific problem but I'm not aware of.

Comment: If there are, there are many billion dollar companies that would love to know, Uber among them.

Comment: Note that shortest path isn't an np-hard problem (_e.g._ because otherwise, since Dijkstra's algorithm runs in polynomial time, the p vs np dilemma would be solved)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand its optimization problem, do we have any packages/libraries to implement this. My real problem deals with 3D (i.e X,Y,Z) coordinates instead of 2D. Will it be solved by AI?

Comment: @RaviBelkhindi, no. Dijkstra's algorithm is already N-dimensional, it does not care about the dimensions of data, just the connectivity. ML is not a magic buzzword, ML will not solve your problems here. An implementation in Python exists, however, you may wish to extend this or write it in C for performance:
https://code.activestate.com/recipes/119466-dijkstras-algorithm-for-shortest-paths/

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderHuszagh

Answer (score 0):

Like others already stated: this is not a typical "Artificial Intelligence" problem. It is kind of a path planning problem.

There are different algorithms available. If your path doesn't neet to satisfy any constraints like .g. smoothness, you can use an A*-Algorithm with distance as heuristic.

You have to represent your XYZ-space as a Graph where each node has a coordinate. Further you need to take into account, that no nodes lie near the points you want to avoid.

If your path needs to satisfy constraints, this turns into a more complicated path planning problem where you could apply optimization or RRTs.